# Dbeaver Postgres backup database connection error

Tags: database, postgresql, dump, database-backups, dbeaver

With Dbeaver version 22.3.1 I connect to Postgres database remotly by a url connection string.
I want to make a dump of db so, right click on db name -> tools -> backup but the dump failed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJtWc.png

Dbeaver tries to connect to localhost:5432, not using url connection. Obviously I can connect to db and make other operations like see db tables, insert row etc...., but not make db dump.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  And your error message image has truncated away the bits that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you can connect db, and start, I have version 22.1.5, last version is 23.
It is easiest to upgrade to the last version and try again. I don't have any problems.
You can also check if your PATH is good when he calls.
For example, I have something like this:

*pg_dump.exe --verbose --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=YourUSer--format=c --file C:\Users\Downloads\dump-YourUSer-202303181417 -t "public.schema" schema*

I suppose that you for the host must have your server-name.
Also you can call  it from the command line then.